# "The orthogonal polynomial" in Gaussian quadrature

Tags: numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials

From [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianQuadrature.html):

> The fundamental theorem of Gaussian quadrature states that the optimal
>   abscissas of the m-point Gaussian quadrature formulas are precisely
>   the roots of the orthogonal polynomial for the same interval and
>   weighting function.

In this context, what is meant by "*the* orthogonal polynomial"?  To be orthogonal is not a property of any particular polynomial, but rather a set of polynomials.  Thanks all!

Comment: The "m point" condition determines the order of the polynomial, and the interval and weighting function determine the orthogonal family to which it belongs. So the definition picks out a specific polynomial.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Will you submit this, along with an example, as an answer?